# Download a blob of a XML directly to local storage

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, download, blob

I managed to generate a XML file to import in my GoogleDrive like this

```
function createXML() {
  var Origine = "Example"

  var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n';
  xml += '<root>\n';
  xml += '  <element>' + Origine + '</element>\n';
  xml += '</root>\n';
  
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(xml, 'application/xml', 'my-xml.xml');
  
  
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
  blob.setName("my-xml.xml");
  folder.createFile(blob);
}
```

But I would like to download this blob as XML file directly on my computer without passing through Google Drive. What could be the easiest solution ?

I tried different method. But I'm not a great coder...

Comment: I would consider using Javascript LocalStorage

Comment: It's not possible to save a file to local storage using only server side code (.gs). You could use HtmlService or ContentService to return the proper object to the client-side so the browser will handle the download.

Comment: I would have used Javascript.